# SQLite Window functions: give NULL result when sufficient window size is not available

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, average, window-functions

```
create table boll as select
     *, (avg(close) over win)-2*sqrt((avg(close*close) over win)-pow((avg(close) over win),2)) as BOLD,
     (avg(close) over win)+2*sqrt((avg(close*close) over win)-pow((avg(close) over win),2)) as BOLU
     from bhav
     window win as (partition by isin order by timestamp rows 19 preceding);
```

With the above query, is there a way to return `NULL` from calculations over window `win` if there are less than 19 rows preceding the current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNT()` window function over the window that you define to check how many rows there are:

```
create table boll as 
select *, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER win >= 19 THEN (avg(close) over win) - 2 * sqrt((avg(close*close) over win)-pow((avg(close) over win),2)) END as BOLD,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER win >= 19 THEN (avg(close) over win)+2*sqrt((avg(close*close) over win)-pow((avg(close) over win),2)) END as BOLU
from bhav
window win as (partition by isin order by timestamp rows 19 preceding);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look 19 timestamps back with `LAG`:

```
create table boll as 
  select *,
  case when lag(timestamp, 19) over (order by timestamp) is not null then
    avg(close) over win) - 2 * sqrt((avg(close*close) over win) - pow((avg(close) over win), 2)
  end as BOLD,
  case when lag(timestamp, 19) over (order by timestamp) is not null then
    avg(close) over win) + 2 * sqrt((avg(close*close) over win) - pow((avg(close) over win), 2) 
  end as BOLU
from bhav
window win as (partition by isin order by timestamp rows 19 preceding);
```